# JSR 352 batch application example

Tags: batch-processing

I am looking for simple example using JSR 352. I would like to write a small batch application using JSR 352. I would like to read from the table and computes the summary..store it in another table.

Answer (score 3):

[Oracle Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/batch-processing.htm#GKJIQ6)

Check "The phonebilling Example Application" and "The webserverlog Example Application".

You can check this too if you only want code:

https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/batch

Answer (score 0):

You can use [netbeans plugin jBatch Suite](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/55031/jbatch-suite) for initial learning and high productivity .
Using it , you can generate source code and batch xml .

See [jBatch Suite Demo here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQt_mtH5Gd8&feature=youtu.be) .