# Java Batch Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, jsr352

I have some JSR-352 batch jobs that run quite well - despite their runtime.
Now I am thinking of distributing the work across several threads.

How is this pattern supported by JSR-352?

Edit: Now that I know the keywords to search for I can make out more resources on this problem:

- [Batch job definition: How to run a dynamically-calculated number of partitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58427625/batch-job-definition-how-to-run-a-dynamically-calculated-number-of-partitions)
- [JSR 352 batch application example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741433/jsr-352-batch-application-example)
- https://github.com/javaee-samples/jakartaee-samples/tree/main/ee7/batch
- https://www.baeldung.com/java-ee-7-batch-processing#partitionof-job
- https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/system/files/inline-files/WP102706_WLB_JSR352.002.pdf page 24+

I want to create a partitioned batchlet, and the partitions must be calculated at runtime. The idea is to split the processing of all records into a predefined maximum number of partitions, or a number of partitions with maximum size.

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/jsr-352.html, section Partitioning.

Comment: Thank you, Partitioning seems the answer. And I do not understand why this question would get downvoted without even a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another [example of using partitioned](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/main/batch-processing/src/main/resources/META-INF/batch-jobs/import-file.xml) chunk processing in JBeret. Partitioned batchlet should be similar in terms of job configuration. But partitioned batchlet is not common compared to partitioned chunk steps, because batchlet is mainly a task-oriented step, which is not easy to split into multiple partitions. So you may want to check if batchlet step is really suitable.

JBeret project [test-apps](https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/tree/master/test-apps) module contains some examples with partition configuration. For example, [cdiScopes](https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/blob/master/test-apps/cdiScopes/stepScoped/src/main/resources/META-INF/batch-jobs/stepScopedPartitioned.xml) tests use batchlet with partitions. [Throttle](https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/blob/master/test-apps/throttle/src/main/resources/META-INF/batch-jobs/throttle.xml) tests use chunk with partitions.

JBeret test-apps/chunkPartition test module contains a [job xml that uses mapper for dynamic partition](https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/blob/master/test-apps/chunkPartition/src/main/resources/META-INF/batch-jobs/org.jberet.test.chunkPartitionRestart2StepsMapper.xml).

Comment: In my case, the batch needs to read records, do some processing and write them back plus maybe create additional information. So far I thought the reader/writer pattern does not apply. Hence I have a batchlet. But there is no reason not to parallelize. Thank you for the example, I will take a look.

Comment: The link you posted does not work for me

Comment: Sorry for the bad link. Now fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the fixed link. Now I am wondering where in that example parallel threads play a role, something I hoped to achieve with partitioning.

Comment: I edited my answer above to include some examples of partitioned chunk and partitioned batchlet.

Comment: The newly referenced examples use partition, thank you. Do you also happen to have one with a dynamically calculated partition?

Comment: I just added to the above answer a link to a job xml that uses dynamic partition.

Comment: How does JBeret handle the ref attributes? I do not see a mapping to class names within the batch xml file.

Comment: Please see [Jakarta Batch Spec](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/batch-api/blob/master/spec/src/main/asciidoc/batch_runtime_spec.adoc#batch-artifact-loading) for details of loading batch classes.